# How do I make scratchboard/etching effects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, brush

I'm having a hard time grasping how to get the same brush stroke with the right proportion of space in between like in this image (Marilyn). I'm sure it wasn't free handedly drawn with a brush tool, it's well proportioned.

[image]

I'm trying to get the same effect so what I did was I'd trace the face with a pen tool and fill it with a line pattern (flat and angular) but the effects are not quite the same as you see in Marilyn (fine and pointed) with white specs breaking up the lines.

[image]

Please assist, I've tried to look up google for tutorials. 
Thank you!

Comment: source image has **a lot** to do with things... and there are plug ins such as [Phantasm](http://www.astutegraphics.com/software/phantasm/) which are marvelous at this.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I found a different way of doing it without using plugins.

Answer (score 4):

The first image appears to have been processed on Adobe Photoshop; it looks like halftone.

Here are the steps described in [a tutorial on halftone](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/photoshop-tutorial-screentones-half-tones-26776.html):

> **Step 1**
>   Open the Photoshop PSD file you want to convert to a halftone by clicking the "File" menu and choosing "Open." This displays the Open dialog box. Navigate to the file, select it, then click "Open."
>
> **Step 2**
>   Click the "Image" menu, choose "Mode," then select "Grayscale." Photoshop displays a dialog box asking if you want to discard the image's color information.
>
> **Step 3**
>   Click "Discard," then Photoshop converts the image to grayscale.
>
> **Step 4**
>   Click the "Image" menu, choose "Mode," and select "Bitmap." This opens the Bitmap dialog box.

Here it asked about the resolution too: I chose 300 dpi just in case you'd like to print it. The "input resolution" was 150 dpi on the image I worked with.

> **Step 5**
>   Click the "Use" drop-down menu and choose "Halftone Screen."
>
> **Step 6**
>   Click "OK." This opens the Halftone Screen dialog box. From here you can change the halftone pattern's frequency measured in lines per inch. For example a halftone with a frequency of 60 lines per inch contains 60 rows of dots, or whatever shape you choose to create your halftone. The Halftone Screen dialog box provides several shape options, such as Round (dots), Diamond, Ellipse, Line, Square, and Cross. Each of these creates a different-looking halftone pattern. Typically, you would use dots to simulate shades of gray and the others to create special effects.
>
> **Step 7**
>   Type the desired frequency in the "Frequency" field.

I chose 10 lines per inch

> **Step 8**
>   Click the "Shape" drop-down menu and choose the desired shape.

On this step I chose 45 degrees angle and "Line" from the shape options, and pressed `OK`

This are my results.

[image: Madonna linear halftone]

Keep in mind that the levels, contrast, resolution, and lines per inch will affect the outcome of the effect.

On the tutorial it says that you can obtain the same result using `Filters > Sketch > Halftone Pattern` but I can’t find it on my version of Photoshop CC (14.2.1 x64), except if I go through `Filter > Filter Gallery`, and then it won't allow me to select the angle of the lines.

[image: Madonna]

Please correct any misspellings as I'm translating the dialogs from my Spanish version of Photoshop.